# Why is SecureRandom in Java called CS PRNG and not TRNG?

Tags: java, prng

SecureRandom internally makes use of other algorithms , like in case of `Linux` , makes use of `NativePRNG` which in turn makes use of `/dev/urandom` . But `/dev/urandom` is actually using interrupts events etc to generate entropy which is similar to a True Random Number Generator (TRNG) . So why is `SecureRandom` called `PseudoRandom` Number Generator , although it is dependent on the implementation of the algorithm it is using ?

Thanks

Comment: /dev/urandom is unblocking random. If it runs out of entropy it will fall back to pseudo randomess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I expect it has to do with guarantees. The guarantee of `/dev/urandom` is that it will use random data if available, filling in with pseudo-random data if necessary to avoid blocking. So if you're using `/dev/urandom`, you can't claim true randomness, even if sometimes you're getting it.

In the [documentation for `SecureRandom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) it says:

> Many `SecureRandom` implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed. Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others may use a combination of both techniques.

Thus, the guarantee of `SecureRandom` can only ever be that it works pseudo-randomly, if any implementations are allowed to do so. It may be able to do better, but that's not the contract.

Comment: But in previous versions of Java , /dev/random was the default one . Still they used to call it a PRNG which might not be true in every case if I am not wrong.

Comment: actually /dev/random is classified as a PRNG in the same way as /dev/urandom

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : Documentation part seems good . 
spikeheap : but why do they call it prng even though it makes use of external entropy ?

Comment: /dev/random being a "true" random generator is a myth: http://sockpuppet.org/blog/2014/02/25/safely-generate-random-numbers/

Answer (score 1):

Not all operating systems implement the same functionality for /dev/random, and there is no guarantee that it will be anything other than an algorithm (though most modern systems do use interrupts, etc). That is why Java refers to it as a PRNG.

/dev/random on Linux is a TRNG.